# how to change parameters of fasttext api in a python script

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, fasttext

We have [fasttext commands](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/README.md#models) to run in command prompt

I have cloned the github repository and for example to change parameters of the network for a supervised learning in the command I used are like

```
 ./fasttext supervised -input FT_Race_data.txt -output race_model  -lr 0.4 -epoch 30 -loss hs
```

I am changing lr and epoch and loss. I can train and fetch the required output.

For programming in python script, I installed the fasttext library and I tried like

```
classifier = fasttext.supervised('FT_Race_data.txt','race_model')
```

The model gets trained but the results are not good, In this case, I didn't define any parameters. So I tried like

```
classifier = fasttext.supervised('FT_Race_data.txt','race_model', 0.4, 30, 'hs')
```

The programs run with no error but don't give any result. So I tried like

```
classifier = fasttext.supervised(input = 'FT_Race_data.txt',output ='race_model', lr = 0.4,epoch= 30,loss = 'hs')
```

it gives an error that fasttext takes only two arguments.

How to change parameters in python script like in command prompt to fine tune the supervised learning ?

Comment: If you installed via cloning the repo and `pip install .` in the cloned folder you could set the parameters using train_supervised as in the following example: https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/python/doc/examples/train_supervised.py#L30

Comment: @tyolan: Thank you ! it worked !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future references, Form discussions [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/436), it seems that the `pip install fasttext` doesn't install the full features available in the [repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText).

So till when the latest features are included in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fasttext, for python bindings with features to train models and set parameters, follow the following installation procedure as outlined [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/README.md#building-fasttext-for-python).

```
git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
cd fastText
pip install .
```

And then using `train_supervised` a function which returns a model object one can set the different parameters as in the following [example in that repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/python/doc/examples/train_supervised.py#L30).

```
fastText.train_supervised(input, lr=0.1, dim=100, ws=5, epoch=5, minCount=1, minCountLabel=0, minn=0, maxn=0, neg=5, wordNgrams=1, loss='softmax', bucket=2000000, thread=12, lrUpdateRate=100, t=0.0001, label='__label__', verbose=2, pretrainedVectors='')
```